# EF exception when trying to seed database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I followed this tutorial to create my own application: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

When I start to debug and try to open tab of Players list, its equivalent to Student tab in these tutorial, I got following exception:

> Exception Details: Object of type 'AzsPkInz.DAL.AZSContext' cannot be converted to type 'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer`1[AzsPkInz.DAL.AZSContext]'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> 1. Line 19:         public ActionResult Index()
> 2. Line 20:         {
> 3. Line 21:             return View(db.Players.ToList());
> 4. Line 22:         }

This is `AZSContext` source:

```
public class AZSContext : DbContext
{
    public AZSContext() : base("AZSContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

And this is a `Player` model:

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollemnts { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea's what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that in your web config the `databaseInitializer` element points to a `IDatabaseInitializer` (such as `SchoolInitializer`) *not* a `AZSContext`.

```
<contexts>
  <context 
      type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
    <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

Comment: Thanks for a answer, I've done mistake in a databaseInitializer. I forgot to change "AzsPkInz.DAL.AZSContext, AzsPkInz" from context type to "AzsPkInz.DAL.AZSInitializer, AzsPkInz" from databaseInitializer when I was copying the string.

Thanks again, I waste few hours to resolve this problem. : )